# How to solve exercise 6.6 from the book Topology by Manetti

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I'm studying topology from Manetti's book and I cannot solve the exercise 6.6, could anybody help me? Especially, I'm not sure about item 2. Thanks a lot.

Take disjoint copies $\mathbb{R}_a$ of the real line, parametrised by a real number $a\in]-\pi/2,\pi/2[$, and define continuous maps
$$f_a:(\mathbb{R}_a-\{0\})\times]-1,1[\to\mathbb{R}^2,$$
$$f_a(x,t)=\left(\frac{\cos(a)}{x}-t\sin(a),\frac{\sin(a)}{x}+t\cos(a)\right).$$
Now consider the disjoint union of $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the strips $\mathbb{R}_a\times]-1,1[$, and denote
$$X=\frac{\mathbb{R}^2\cup\cup_a\mathbb{R}_a\times]-1,1[}{\sim}$$
the quotient under the smallest equivalence relation $\sim$ such that
$$(x,t)\sim f_a(x,t),\quad \mbox{for every}\quad (x,t)\in(\mathbb{R}_a-\{0\})\times]-1,1[.$$

Prove that

1. $X$ is connected, separable and Hausdorff; each point an open neighbourhood homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$;
2. $X$ contains a discrete subset whose cardinality is more than countable. In particular, $X$ isn't second countable;
3. $X$ can't be written as countable union of compact sets.